# Windows Simple Batch "Multithread" Processing

Tags: multithreading, batch-file, for-loop, text, windows-7

Hi I am pushed by deadlines, so I will post my question here as I go along with my search..here is my script, all it does is look at **every file of a folder**, and create different **"list.txt"** depending of the *value* of **"tree_size.txt"** formated as CSV.txt (filename,size):

```
FOR %%I in (%inputDir%\*.*) DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2" %%A IN (%tree_size%) DO (
        IF %%~nxI==%%A IF %%B LEQ 10.000 (
            echo %%~dpnxI >> %inputDir%\0_10.txt)
        IF %%~nxI==%%A IF %%B GTR 10.000 IF %%B LEQ 25.000 (
            echo %%~dpnxI >> %inputDir%\11_25.txt)
        IF %%~nxI==%%A IF %%B GTR 25.000 IF %%B LEQ 40.000 (
            echo %%~dpnxI >> %inputDir%\26_40.txt)
        IF %%~nxI==%%A IF %%B GTR 40.000 IF %%B LEQ 55.000 (
            echo %%~dpnxI >> %inputDir%\41_55.txt)
        IF %%~nxI==%%A IF %%B GTR 55.000 (
            echo %%~dpnxI >> %inputDir%\56_plus.txt)
        )
    )
```

My aim is to modify this code in order to use **multithread processing**, which seams to be an option using batch scripting on Windows 7.

Comment: Why do you think that? Why do you want to do that? The disk cache should prevent the harm that moving the heads back and forth to different parts of the disk would do to speed and battery life as you don't write. The basic multithreading on Windows for you is different processes. But you don't really want to do that.

Comment: I might have 50,000 files who need to be classified by using the values of one text file, and I need the file names to be listed into five different lists, those list, as you can see in the code, are called 0_10.txt, 11_25.txt, 26_40.txt, 41_55.txt and 56_plus.txt. Now, I was thinking about Multithreading the process, since this code take ONE file at a time, and it takes forever to process 50,000... I need one of the two answer to the question, is this possible, or not, if yes, who can I achieve this? I have a 48 cores xeon CPU and 192(256) GB RAM, and I want to speed the process.

Comment: It's the hard disk that matters. All your threads will be lined up waiting for the hard disk. And as I said *The basic multithreading on Windows for you is different processes*.

Comment: Batch file is the wrong technology. It is by magnitudes slower than every other technology. Asking how to do something impossible in batchfile makes it (wrong technology)^2 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is one of approach.

As you have 50,000 files and assuming you have 50,000 lines in your `tree_size` file (of which you've not given us a sample) then you are reading `tree_size` 50,000 times and executing the `if` tree 50,000 * 50,000 = 2,500,000,000 times. Each of your comparison blocks makes 5 tests each time = 12,500,000,000 tests.

Try this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2" %%A IN (%tree_size%) DO if exist "%inputDir%\%%A" (
        IF %%B LEQ 10.000 (
            echo %inputDir%\%%A >> %inputDir%\0_10.txt
        ) else (
        IF %%B LEQ 25.000 (
            echo %inputDir%\%%A >> %inputDir%\11_25.txt
        ) else (
        IF %%B LEQ 40.000 (
            echo %inputDir%\%%A >> %inputDir%\26_40.txt
        ) else (
        IF %%B LEQ 55.000 (
            echo %inputDir%\%%A >> %inputDir%\41_55.txt
        ) else (
            echo %inputDir%\%%A >> %inputDir%\56_plus.txt
        )))))
    )
```

which should accomplish the same thing using  only 50,000 cycles of the inner loop.

Comment: Thanks for your time Magoo.. this is a good improvement already. I can't give you a point for the answer, but yes, this is the answer man